# MapReduce is not sorting

Tags: python, sorting, mapreduce

I'm using python to develop a mapreduce program, when I use map.py and reduce.py by comand line:

```
cat passengers.dat | python map.py | sort | python reduce.py
```

The result is good. But if I try to use mapreduce:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.2.0.10.0-1.jar -input passengers.dat -output /out -file map.py -file reduce.py -mapper map.py -reducer  reduce.py
```

The result is wrong because it seems not sorting before reducing.

I draw this conclusion because by command line:

```
cat passengers.dat | python map.py | sort
```

The result is:

```
141181  2014    5   1   0   STA 267
141181  2014    5   1   1   END 1031
141181  2014    5   1   4   STA 1031
141181  2014    5   1   5   END 267
```

But when I rewrite my reduce to write the lines 'reduce' receives to understand what is the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys 
for line in sys.stdin:
        print line
```

The result is not sorted:

```
141181  2014    5   1   1   END 1031
141181  2014    5   1   0   STA 267
141181  2014    5   1   5   END 267
141181  2014    5   1   4   STA 1031
```

the fifth column is disordered !!! Why??!

thank you

I post my SOLUTION below!!

Comment: I can't replicate everything you did but I created a python program that prints every line of input likes yours then passes it to sort. I piped in your unsorted input to start with and it printed out everything sorted. So I am not sure what to tell you.

Comment: thank you AtlasMeh-ed I've solved the problem. :)

Comment: You should [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: Thanks, before I couldn't post my answer, now yes

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, the problem was that mapreduce uses key-value and there are too many keys, so the solution I have implemented is to rewrite mapper to return:

```
return 'value1#value2#value3#value4#value5#value6 \t value7'
```

By this way mapreduce sort perfectly the key and I can split on reducer.

I hope it will be useful

Comment: Old post but led me to finding the default separator after the map stage is '\t' (see [3.3.0 docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.0/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#How_Streaming_Works)) you can change it with `-D stream.map.output.field.separator=.` (to a full stop in this case, or whatever you wish).